# In an excel how to remove/filter all the lines except the record matching a particular pattern?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet with 7 fields.

I want to remove/filter all the records that donot have string `/inf/` in the 5th field.

How can I acheieve this?

### Input

```
F1     F2    F3   F4     F5    F6    F7
------------------------------------------

1      2      3   4    A/inf/B  5     6
1      2      3   4     5       6     7
1      2      3   4     6       7     8 
5      6      7   8    A/inf/B  9     2
```

### Output

```
F1     F2    F3   F4     F5    F6    F7
------------------------------------------
1      2      3   4    A/inf/B  5     6
5      6      7   8    A/inf/B  9     2
```

Please help.

Thanks,
Srihari

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a column to the right of the data with the formula

```
=if(iserror(find("/inf/",E2)),1,0)
```

and then sort the data, and delete the records with that have a value of 1. (I'm assuming that column 'F5' corresponds to column E and that you're starting in row 2, but the formula can easily be changed to work with your data).

Comment: Thanks Jubbles I have done this way and filtered all rows with value 0 it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DeleteNonInfRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim r As Long
    For r = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Cells(r, 5), "/inf/") = 0 Then Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next r
End Sub
```